# Dotted lines in highcharts.net

Tags: highcharts

When I having a Line chart, how do I make so some of the lines is having dots in them for example? Right now I only get the normal lines that are used in their examples

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything at all ? A simple google search  will give you answer. Check highchart docs and you will have answer.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.dashStyle

You can use `dashStyle: ''` option which you can check in their sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle/).